# Send Email using SMTP in web api vs asmx service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asmx

I am trying to send notification email in ASP.NET Web API. Following is the code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/UpdateUser")]
    public Foo UpdateUser(Foo vm)
    { 
       /* some data base operations here....
       ......
       ......
             */
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("<SMTP Server>", 587);

        mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        mail.To.Add("toemail@test.com");
        mail.Subject = "You are subject";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = "Hello My Dear User";


        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        Foo newVM = new Foo();

    }
```

But it throws following error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. 
---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond <server IP>:587 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 
--- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) 
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Now, i created an entirely new asp.net web project and placed same code in an asmx service (SOAP), and call it using soap client tools, it works just fine..

i deployed both in two separate IIS applications on same (test environment)server, only difference is web.api is a part of a **ASP.NET MVC** Application where as asmx service part of **asp.net web** application.

Result:
asmx service works but WEB API errors out with above error message.

Question is why ? what am i missing ?
I searched around and found following configuration could help

```
  <system.net>
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

:( but unfortunately in my case it didn't help...

Any one faced such issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("yourmail");
mailMessage.To.Add("akash073@waltonbd.com");
mailMessage.CC.Add("akash073@gmail.com");
mailMessage.Subject = "Test";
mailMessage.Body = "Test";
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "your host";
smtp.Port = 25;//your port
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: What is the difference ??, Anyway i tried it but not success i get the same error...

Comment: mine works fine if its implemented in asmx web service. But if implement the same in ASP.NET WEB API, it doesn't work.